# Fetch all records from store using localstorage proxy

Tags: extjs

I  have created a form using sencha touch 2.1 having three Textfield. 
i want to do user insert info into textField and save into store.then fetch all the records from store and display on console.i try below code but it gives errors. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for".

```
listeners:
                        {

                            tap:function()
                            {
                                var i,row;
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Hi');
                                var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', 
                                {
                                    model: 'LoginDemo.model.User'

                                });
                                var n=Ext.getCmp('txtname').getValue();
                                var a=Ext.getCmp('txtadd').getValue();
                                var e=Ext.getCmp('txtemail').getValue();

                                //loads any existing Search data from localStorage
                                store.load();
                                //now add some Searches
                                store.add({name: n,add: a,mail:e}),

                                //finally, save our Search data to localStorage

                                for(i=0;i<store.getAllCount();i++)
                                {
                                    row=store.getAt(i);
                                    store.sync();
                                    console.log(row);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                     },
can you suggest me what i do wrong in code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
store.add({name: n,add: a,mail:e}),
```

There should be a semicolon at the end of that line, not a comma.

Comment: i used array to store the element and push new element @ the end of array then it works fine.

Comment: here is code var arr=[];
        arr.push(n,a,e);
        store.add(arr);
        for(i=0;i<store.getAllCount();i++)
        {
         row=store.getAt(i);
         store.sync();
         console.log(row);
        }